# Call Share Intent in Fragment actionbar

Tags: android, fragment

hi this is my code and when i run app and click icon share, do not show share

how fix it?

```
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;


public class BioActivity extends Fragment {

  private MenuItem mRefreshMenuItem;


  @
  Nullable@ Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_bio, container, false);

  }

  @
  Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
  }

  @
  Override
  public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.share, menu);
  }

  @
  Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.action_share:
        TextView textView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.text_bio);
        String string = textView.getText().toString();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, string);
        return true;
      default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
  }
}
```

...

Comment: you didn't call `startActivity`. call `getActivity().startActivity(..)`, because its a fragment

Comment: i try getActivity(); and startActivity(); both do not work

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to include `startActivity(intent);` which is the piece of code that will execute the intent, and thus start the share dialog.
An even better solution would be to use the chooser:
`startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));`

You can find more information on sharing in the Android documentation: http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html

Comment: i add startActivity(intent); but again do not run intent

Comment: Is onOptionItemSelected being called? Your onOptionItemSelected on your Activity should return false because the Activity has not handled it.
PS you could remove // TODO Auto-generated method stub when you implemented a function. Tip: start using Android Studio!

Comment: Did you check @DalvikVM 's comment? You should make sure the activity that hosts the fragment is not blocking the `onOptionsItemSelected` callback. Try adding some logging all over the place to see where your code gets stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I used to use this approach, and it works, try yourself:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_readinglist_activity,
            menu);

    MenuItem actionItem = menu.findItem(R.id.reading_share);
    ShareActionProvider actionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) actionItem
            .getActionProvider();

    Intent intent = getDefaultShareIntent();
    if (intent != null)
        actionProvider.setShareIntent(intent);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private Intent getDefaultShareIntent() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, titleR);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, handleR);
    return intent;
}
```

Comment: getSupportMenuInflater() and return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu); get error?!

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
myIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(context, Intent.createChooser(myIntent, "Share Options"),null);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) helps to improve the quality of your response. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.